# Why my Select statement does not return any data?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select, join

I've created two tables with a foreign key. The insertion of data has succeeded, but when I use a SELECT statement then no data is showing. The code is below.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_BLOCK_LIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST
            + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0,"
            + ORIGINATING_ADDRESS + " TEXT)";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS
            + "(" + ID_BLOCKED_SMS + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0, "
            + MESSAGE_BODY + " TEXT,"
            + FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST + " INTEGER," +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + FK_ID_BLOCK_LIST + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_BLOCK_LIST + "(" + ID_BLOCK_LIST +"))";
```

SELECT statement

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            //cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BLOCKED_SMS, null);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_block_list " +
                    "JOIN table_blocked_sms " +
                    "ON table_block_list.id_block_list = table_blocked_sms.id_blocked_sms" , null);
```

Kindly guide me where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join is implicitly `INNER JOIN`.

If your first table has data and your second one does not, an INNER JOIN will return no data.

What you need to do is use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM table_block_list
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_blocked_sms
        ON table_blocked_sms.id_blocked_sms = table_block_list.id_block_list
```

Comment: sorry i changed my code as per my requirement. now again its not working cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_block_list" +
                    " LEFT OUTER JOIN table_blocked_sms" +
                    " ON table_block_list.id_block_list = table_blocked_sms.fk_id_block_list" , null);                                                 please help @yk11

Comment: What do you get back? no results? an error code?  Can you start by ensuring both tables have data and using an inner join?